# How to resolve Exception in thread error (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

This code is to input `n` `integer` values and calculate the no. of `even` and `odd` values among those inputted values.

This java code shows `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when used `do..while` loop, however when used `for` loop it worked fine. Haven't changed any thing just rearranged the syntax so as to convert `for` loop into `do while` loop.

FOR LOOP:

```
import java.util.*;

public class EvenOddCount
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    System.out.print("Enter the no. of inputs to be taken : ");
    int evenCount=0, oddCount=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the inputs : ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]%2==0)
            evenCount++;
        else 
            oddCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("\nThe number of even numbers in input numbers are : "+evenCount);
    System.out.println("The number of odd numbers in input numbers are : "+oddCount);
}
}
```

The above code works fine and gives suitable output.

DO...WHILE LOOP:

```
import java.util.*;

public class EvenOddCount
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    System.out.print("Enter the no. of inputs to be taken : ");
    int evenCount=0, oddCount=0, i=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the inputs : ");
    do
    {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        i++;
    } while (i<n);
    do
    {
        if(a[i]%2==0)
            evenCount++;
        else 
            oddCount++;
        i++;
    } while (i<a.length);
    System.out.println("\nThe number of even numbers in input numbers are : "+evenCount);
    System.out.println("The number of odd numbers in input numbers are : "+oddCount);
}
}
```

The above code has a runtime exception i.e.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at EvenOddCount.main(EvenOddCount.java:20)
```

Comment: That's because do-while loops always execute at least once due to the condition being evaluated after. In your second do while loop, `int i` is still the same value as it was on the last iteration of the first do-while, and thus out range when doing `a[i]%2`

Comment: @Li357 Thanks. I corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your original code, you had two separate `i` variables:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
...

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
```

In your `do/while` version, you've got *one* `i` variable. Once you've gone through the first loop, the value of `i` will be `n` - but you start on the second loop without resetting it to 0, so on the very first iteration it will be out of range.

You can fix that by adding:

```
i = 0;
```

just before the second `do`/`while` loop, but be aware that you'll *still* have a problem (even in the first loop) if `n` is 0, because you're not checking the condition until the end of the iteration. If you use:

```
while (i < n)
```

and

```
while (i < a.length)
```

instead, that will check the condition before the first iteration, so it will execute 0 times when `n` is 0. (You still need to reset `i` to 0 before the second loop though.)

Comment: Thanks A Lot Sir! Actually I have to specifically code using do..while loop hence I can't use while hence for the problem about input n=0 I'll have to use if-else.

Answer (score 0):

U need to reset the value of i :

```
do
{
    a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    i++;
} while (i<n);
i =0;
do
{
    if(a[i]%2==0)
        evenCount++;
    else 
        oddCount++;
    i++;
} while (i<a.length);
```

Comment: Doesn't the loop exits as soon as i becomes equal to n.

Comment: @meisner97 yes but i is declared as a class variable, which means the value of i is updated and " remembered ", that is why u need to reset. unlike local variables; which get destroyed as soon as the method finish executing

Comment: @abdalnaseerghzawi okay I understood. Thanks

Comment: @AbdalnassirGhzawi The i variable in the code you've shown is still a local variable.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes my bad, forget it is in main method